# Progress Bar trava a aplicação

Tags: delphi

Estou tentando incrementar um `progressbar` dentro da minha estrutura de repetição, porém o `progressbar` sempre trava a aplicação. Vou demonstrar aqui, segue o código:

---

***Seria correto tentar usar desta forma?***

```delphi
ProgressBar1.Position:=0;
While ... do
begin

     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.Close;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Clear;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('SELECT count(*) FROM cupatres WHERE numcupom = :pcoo2 ');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('AND NSerie = :pecf1 AND ccf = :pccf3 AND Retorno = :pret4 ');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('AND diavenda BETWEEN "'+pdate1treg+'" AND "'+pdate2treg+'"');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pcoo2').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pccf3').AsString := copy(lTemp,53,6);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pret4').AsString := copy(lTemp,59,3);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pecf1').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.Open;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.FetchAll;
     rc1 := DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.RecordCount-1;



ProgressBar1.Max := rc1;
ProgressBar1.Position:= ProgressBar1.Position+1;
   Sleep(50);
   Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Comment: Qual é o "código aqui"? Certeza que é o progressbar? Funciona sem ele?

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, funciona sem problemas sem ele (progressbar), o código é enorme.

Comment: O código enorme acessa banco? Você consegue saber se o sistema congela enquanto está executando o while sem ter o progressbar lá?

Comment: Tente adicionar `application.processmessages;` no lugar do sleep. Se der certo formulo uma resposta explicando o pq.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, o código acessa banco sim, estou testando com o `application.processmessages;`, se der certo eu retorno! Obrigado!

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, deu certo sim, ele passou o codigo direitinho, porém, o progressbar não processa, ele fica parado em 100%.

Comment: Eu te desencorajaria a utilizar o sleep a menos que tenha uma razão clara para isso. Ele faz com que o processador faço swap de threads e não auxiliar em nada ao andamento do metodo e demorando mais meio segundo em cada etapa do loop para o usuario

Comment: @Caputo, o que encorajaria então amigo? Queria algo que fizesse o progress bar rodar sem travar ;/

Comment: Estamos com um problema grande aqui agora. Mas no fim da tarde posto um exemplo de como fazer. Uma dúvida: Qual o maxvalue de sua progress bar? como está calculando ele? No seu exemplo não mostra a definição do maxvalue

Comment: @Caputo, esse é o problema, por que quando coloco o maxvalue do progressbar, que no caso seria o record count do query, mas, nao me retorna nada, acredito q a quantidade de registros esta pegando de outro canto.

Comment: @DBX8, é pq na verdade. ele está apenas entrando no banco de dados para pegar e comparar os registros que preciso, ele não estar percorrendo o banco de dados completamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz um while apenas para contar a quantidade de registros encontrados, segue o código:

```
//contando registros
  AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
  Reset(txt);
  while not eof(txt) do
  begin
    Readln(txt, lTemp);
    btnLoadCup.Enabled := false;

    if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E01') then
    begin
      date1 := StrToDateTime(copy(lTemp, 134,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp, 132,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp, 128,4));
      date2 := StrToDateTime(copy(lTemp, 142,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp, 140,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,
      136,4));
      date1treg := FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd', date1);
      date2treg := FormatDateTime('yyyy/MM/dd', date2);
    end;

    if  (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') then
    begin
       dtcompra:=StrToDateTime(copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4));
       dtcompratxt:= FormatDateTime('dd/MM/yyyy', dtcompra);

       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT count(*) FROM tdcupant WHERE numcupom = :co2 AND ccf = :cc3 AND dtcompra = :dtc4 AND impcaixa = :ip5 ');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('AND dtcompra BETWEEN "'+date1treg+'" AND "'+date2treg+'"');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('co2').AsString := copy(lTemp,53,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('cc3').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ip5').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtc4').AsDate := StrToDate(dtcompratxt);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FetchAll;
       rc1 := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.RecordCount;


      if  (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E15') then
      begin
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.Close;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Clear;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('SELECT count(*) FROM cupatres WHERE numcupom = :pcoo2 ');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('AND NSerie = :pecf1 AND ccf = :pccf3 AND Retorno = :pret4 ');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.SQL.Add('AND diavenda BETWEEN "'+pdate1treg+'" AND "'+pdate2treg+'"');
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pcoo2').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pccf3').AsString := copy(lTemp,53,6);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pret4').AsString := copy(lTemp,59,3);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.ParamByName('pecf1').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.Open;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.FetchAll;

        rc2 := DModuleGrid.ZQuery3.RecordCount;
        ProgressBar1.Max := rc1+rc2;
      end;
    end;
  end;
closeFile(txt);
```

Valeu, obrigado pessoal.

Answer (score 4):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
ProgressBar1.Position:=0;
While ... do
begin

  //codigo aqui

  ProgressBar1.Position:= ProgressBar1.Position+1;
  Sleep(500);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

O comando [Application.ProcessMessages](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/ProcessMessages_%28Delphi%29) faz o que o nome mesmo diz, processa as mensagens que estão pendentes no seu sistema.

O `progressbar` não travava sua aplicação, só não avançava porque o sistema estava *"congelado"* fazendo o que sua rotina mandou.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54640/discussion-on-answer-by-filipe-fonseca-progress-bar-trava-a-aplicacao)